# Issue with a storyboard that is running before a template changes

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, datatemplate

In a list view I change multiple datatemplates as follows.

```
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FileDownloading}" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="Complete" />
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=FileExists}" Value="False" />
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FileMissing}" />
                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" Value="Complete" />
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=FileExists}" Value="True" />
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FileCompleted}" />
                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>

                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

In the window resources I have a storyboard which amoungst other things includes this.

```
                   <Storyboard x:Key="sbShowDeleteIcon">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="gridWait" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
```

In one of the datatemplates when the mouse is over an item then the opacity of a grid with Target named gridWait is changed.

The problem that exists is that if the storyboard above is currently in use as the mouse is over this item and the StyleTriggers changed the datatemplate then the storyboard causes an error as it cannot find gridWait anymore.

**What have I tried?**

1. I added a fake element with the name gridWait to the other
   datatemplates. But the storyboard still had a problem.
2. I only needed the storyboard for 1 datatemplate so I moved the
   storyboard from Window.Resources to a resource of an element within
   this single datatemplate.  This also failed.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: did you mean to tag vb.net?

Comment: yep that is what is used for code behind in WPF. Possibly might add to the solution.

Comment: Is the C# tag useful then?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, what you really need to do is implement a `DataTemplateSelector`

http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html